# kinect (openni): pointcloud2. Object shadow appearing in rviz?

Tags: kinect, rviz, depth-registered, camera, points

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All,

I have a Kinect sensor displaying pointcloud2 data in rviz with RGB8 Color transformer mode using /camera/depth_registered/points topic. Image looks great except for a large shadow appearing offset of all objects within the Kinect's field of view.

I would like to remove this, as it would interfere with object detection I would assume?

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51716/kinect-(openni):-pointcloud2.-object-shadow-appearing-in-rviz?/) by [Andrius](https://answers.ros.org/users/3812/andrius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Andrius, welcome to ROS Answers.

I'm not 100% sure of exactly what you are seeing, but I think what you are talking about is just the natural result of occlusion. Think about it: the rays projected by the Kinect spread in a diverging pattern, so if there is an object in the foreground the stuff that is immediately around it in the 2D image is further away and therefore more spread out. As such, you can't remove it!

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2